# How affect marketing Channel Rule. processing for the link below?

Tags: javascript, web-analytics, adobe-analytics

I noticed that my /JPMFdocs linking convention is properly passing the campaign code value into my sProp 7, but not into any of the campaign eVars (v0, v8, etc).  How will this affect the marketing Channel Rule processing for the link below?

https://www.jpmorganfunds.com/cm/satellite?pagename=jpmfCommon/Utilities/jpmfGetDocument&filename=BRO-MI-QP.pdf

Kindly reply me ASAP.

Thanks in advance!
Jay

Answer (score 0):

Marketing Channels are completely customizable, so everything is going to depend on your Marketing Channel Processing Rules.

1. Within Adobe Analytics, go to Star Menu | Admin Tools | Report Suites
2. Select the report suite, then go to Edit Settings | Marketing Channels | Processing Rules
3. The variables specified in this section determine the Marketing Channel each hit is assigned to.

If you're using prop7 to specify campaign code values, marketing channels aren't affected in any way. If they use s.campaign, eVar8, or other variables you've set to identify campaigns, chances are you're not collecting marketing channel data correctly.